# Date Mapping and Timestamp Convert to date Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, web, mapping

I'm having error it says that "Objects are not valid as a React child. if you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead" here is my code.

```
 const timestamp = Object.keys(data).map((id, index) => {
      var startDate = data[id].start_date.seconds
      var start_date = new Date(startDate*1000);
      console.log(start_date)
//Tue Nov 30 2021 03:00:00 GMT+0800 (Standard Time)//
      return [
        index + 1,
        data[id].eventTitle,
        data[id].venue,
        start_date, ///error here
        data[id].end_date.seconds,
]})


<MUIDataTable data={timestamp}/>
```

Comment: It would be better if you included a link to the library documentation, since this `MUIDataTable` is not yours. That way, the person to answer has the chance to understand the issue better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, as stated clearly in the error message, is that you are passing a Date object. The documentation in https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables clearly states the following:
"Data used to describe table. Must be either an array containing objects of key/value pairs with values that are strings or numbers, or arrays of strings or numbers"

Therefore, you should transform the date object to a string in the format you want, let's say `start_date.toLocaleString()` for example